# HTML5 Canvas: Moving/panning world with arrow keys in EaselJS

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, easeljs

After a year of studying and experimenting through trial-and-error, I feel that I am starting to understand JavaScript a bit more. So, now, I wanna try my hand at writing a simple 2D platform game (think Super Mario World or Sonic the Hedgehog). For this, I'll be employing the EaselJS library.

I am trying to figure out how I can move/pan the 'world' within a canvas by use of the left and right arrow keys. I know how I can run a function upon a `keydown` of the arrow key, but I'm not too sure how I should approach the moving/panning.

[image: Visualisation]

Should I adjust the position/coordinates of every single thing within the canvas when a key is pressed?
Or should I perhaps put everything in a container and move the position/coordinates of the container?

I'll appreciate anything that nudges me into the right direction. Tyvm :)

**Updated with answer**
[The chosen answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17242545/1508933) confirmed that I indeed had to put everything in a [container](http://www.createjs.com/Docs/EaselJS/classes/Container.html) so that I can set the position of that container. This is the code I drafted, and it works.

```
// Canvas
var stage = new createjs.Stage('game');
createjs.Ticker.addEventListener('tick', tick);
function tick(event) {
    stage.update();
}

// Cave
var cave = new createjs.Bitmap('img/cave.png');
cave.x = cave.y = 0;

// World
// Pans World if the left or right arrow keys are pressed
var world = new createjs.Container();
world.x = 0;
world.y = 0;
world.addChild(cave);
stage.addChild(world);
$(window).keydown(function(e){
    switch (e.which || e.keyCode){
        case 39: // right arrow key
            world.regX += 10;
            break;
        case 37: // left arrow key
            world.regX -= 10;
            break;
    }
});
```

I tried updating `world.x` as well as `world.regX`. Somehow, `world.regX` seems to go smoother.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the best way is to put all display objects which will be scrolled into a scrollableObjectContainer (perhaps you have static elements like lifebar).

So when you move, just update scrollableObjectContainer.regX.

You can use tweenJS for a smoother scroll.

Comment: I am going to sound very stupid now, but what is a scrollableObjectContainer? I couldn't find it in the EaselJS API, or on Google.

Comment: Just a container, i named it like that.

Comment: any idea how I could go about adding the tween? I'm trying different variations of `createjs.Tween.get(world).to({regX: world.regX+10}, 100);` but understandbly, this is bound to be laggy (because a typical keydown is held for multiple seconds instead of just a single hit)

Comment: try createjs.Tween.get(world, {override:true})

Answer (score 1):

Just an idea... but take a look at the canvas translate function and use it at the beginning of each redraw to set the context from which to draw everything else.

http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-transform-translate-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

Usually I would agree with EaselJS for most canvas related projects, however the type of game you want to build would be better suited for melonJS.

Check it out http://melonjs.org

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample of 2d top down scroll and rotation following a player.

https://jsfiddle.net/StaticDelvar/bt9ntuL5/

But it boils down to:

```
world.regX = player.x;
world.regY = player.y;
world.rotation = -player.rotation;
```

Then everything including the player goes into the World container and will be rotated as the player moves. GUI must be after world so it draws on top of it.

- Stage

  - World

    - Objects
    - Player
  - Gui